# Call external Web API from MVC project with windows Auth

Tags: c#, windows-authentication

I have an existing MVC application that I inherited from someone else.

I am now trying to take some of the API calls from the old application and move them into a new application.

The problem is, when the MVC application tries to call the API calls in the new application, it gets a 401.2 (unauthorised) response.

I have read that 401.2 means that the front end and the back end are using different authentication protocols, which would make sense to me.

Here is a snip of the response headers for the account call in the new application:
[image]

and here is a snip of the same response headers when calling the same API from the old application:
[image]

This looks to me like they are using different protocols - am I correct? The main difference seems to be the 'WWW-Authenticate:Negotiate' on the failed request - but I do not know how I can fix this?

If so, can anyone advise what I need to change in my MVC project to make it use the Auth type of the first project?

Both aps use the same database if that is any help?

I know this question is a bit vague, but I have no idea where to look to fix this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Are they both MVC Applications? Is one of them an Web API ? How are you making the call? ajax? server side?

Comment: @ZoiloReyes one is MVC and one is WebAPI. I am making the call using AJAX

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET Identity on both your MVC project and WEB Api?

Comment: @ZoiloReyes yes I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a Single Sign-on to maintain your credentials through different apps, you could:

- Use [Identity Server 4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) or [Identity Server 3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) To generate token credentials for you WEB API Projects.
  [MVC](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html)
  [JS](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/jsGettingStarted.html)
- User Forms authentication on your mvc Projects:
  [Example](http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc)
- Use cookie based Authorization:
  [Cookie authorization with OWIN](https://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/)

I recommend Using Identity Server.